# nodejs mysql post method return an old unknow record

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

i have problem with post method in mysql node js, when i post the request in postman it return an old record i don't know where come from.
in the first i used Get method and it worked very well but when i changed the method to Post i found thid problem.

i use this request for a form in react app i think the problem is not in the form because i tried the request in postman before try it in the app.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();

// Connection Mysql

const selectQuery = 'SELECT * FROM userstab';

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'nodeusers',
});

connection.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
        return err;
    }
});

console.log(connection);

// Connection Express Body-Parser Cors

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello from the products server')
});

app.post('/userss/add', (req, res) => {
    const nom = req.body.nom;
    const prenom = req.body.prenom;
    const adresse = req.body.adresse;
    const email = req.body.email;
    console.log(nom, prenom);
    const insertQuery = `INSERT INTO userstab (nom, prenom, adresse, 
                          email) VALUES 
                          ("${nom}","${prenom}","${adresse}",
                         "${email}")`;
    connection.query(insertQuery,[nom,prenom,adresse,email], 
    (err,results) => {
     if(err) {
            res.send(err)
        }
        console.log(nom, prenom);
        res.send({ error: false, data: results, message: 'user has 
        been added successfully.' });

    })
}); 

// First Get request/////////////////////////////////////////

app.get('/userss/add', (req, res) => {
    const { nom, prenom, adresse, email } = req.query;
    const insertQuery = `INSERT INTO userstab (nom, prenom, adresse, email) VALUES ('${nom}','${prenom}','${adresse}','${email}')`;
    connection.query(insertQuery, (err, results) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.send(err)
        }
        else {
            return res.send('successfully added user')
        }
    });    
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Users server worked on port 4000...')
});
```

Comment: What does this "old record" look like?

Comment: firstName lastName password and email, and in my new table where i post there is not password

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever insert a password, so that might solve the password bit. But in what way does the returned record not look as you're expected (like what is expected and what is actually returned)?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `users` table in post request , and another table called `userstab` in get request.

So please change you query in post request to be the same table in get request.

Comment: yes, that because i changed de table in the second query

Comment: So that's the cause of problem, or you intend to link with two tables, of you mean users table has the prob retrieve, old cloum password, connect to db by workbench or any other app check the table schema make sure that schema doesn't has password, try to drop the schema and create new one.